# Importing HTML in WORD

Tags: html, import, ms-word, html-table

I have a question for you, and I don't find an explanation on Google.

I try to import simple html pages in Word with some simple `<h1> <h2>` and `<table>` objects.

When I do a COPY/PASTE on word I would like to keep the fact that `<h1>` can be translated in heading1 in Word Styles for changing the global style in few month.
I will have more than 100 h1 and h2 titles.

I search too a solution to import a simple table and changing in word the table style for all the table in the word document.

Comment: how this is programming related ?

Comment: guess you could try to open your html in a browser and copy the text from the browser to word. it's working in google docs.